# What is the Eclipse shortcut for "public static void main(String args[])"?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, program-entry-point

I know a cool shortcut for `System.out.println()`: sysout <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Is there something similar for `public static void main(String args[])`?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

This is just `main` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 50):

In Eclipse, select preferences.

In preferences, look for Java/Editor/Templates.

Here you will see a list of all of them. And you can even add your own.

Answer (score 19):

Just type `ma` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, you will get an option for it.

Comment: Just type `m` and press `Ctrl` + `Space`, you will get an option for it. :D

Comment: Just press `Ctrl` + `Space` and you will get a list that you later can choose it from.

Comment: I am using mac, so Ctrl+Space is only brings up the spotlight, instead of auto complete.

Answer (score 5):

As bmargulies mentioned:

**Preferences>Java>Editor>Templates>New...**

[image]

[image]

Now, type psvm then `Ctrl + Space` on Mac or Windows.

Comment: Above steps are useful but 'main' is already available in the template. enter main and then ctrl + space.

Comment: Why adding a new template when main is already present?

Answer (score 1):

Type `main` and press and hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and next press <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> (double space) and select, it or press<kbd>enter</kbd> to focus on main option.

This is fastest way.

Comment: The shortcut is wrong, it is correctly stated in the accepted answer.

Comment: are you sure that you are in  Eclipse...it is a general trick ctrl +double space is always served for  Eclipse ... you can try ..however this is correct in my  Eclipse

Comment: my answer is general and can use in Eclipse jee version but accepted answer not enough for eclipse jee also my answer is for all versions of eclipse

Comment: in general case `ctrl  + space + space` is to show all shortcuts that eclipse is made but `ctrl+space` is contained Classes and shortcuts..by double space way we can seperate these from Classes

Answer (score 1):

> To get public static void main(String[] args) line in eclipse without
> typing the whole line type "main" and press Ctrl + space then, you
> will get the option for the main method select it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you can start a program containing the line with **one click.**

*Just select the method stub for it when creating the new Java class, where the code says,*

Which method stubs would you like to create?

*[check-box]* public static void main(String[]args)  **<---- Select this one.**

*[check-box]* Constructors from superclass

*[check-box]* Inherited abstract methods

Answer (score -1):

Just type main and press Ctrl + Space, and you will get an option for it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This has already been stated in the accepted answer.