# How to launch program in psvm?

Tags: java, runtime, program-entry-point, runnable, process.start

How to launch a program in `psvm` with one command?
How does the application know which class to launch first?

I know that `psvm` should only have starting command and nothing more.

Could you explain this to me?

I mean how to create proper `public static void main(String[] args)` in a simple program on Maven. Should I create a class i.e. `Starter` with method `run` (with sequence actions) and in `psvm` write new `Starter().run()`?

Comment: not clear what is it you are asking,  are you talking about how JVM starts and run your, main class? or something else?

Comment: I mean how to create proper public static void main(String[] args) in simple program on Maven. I should create class i.e. Starter with method called run (with sequence actions) and in psvm write new Starter().run();?

Comment: it's configurable, maven and JVM provides you different option to configure your main class

Comment: Add the author's clarification in the comment to main text of question.

Comment: With both NetBeans and IntelliJ, you can type "psvm" then press Tab and the IDE will fill in "`public static void main(String[] args) { }` for you.

Answer (score 3):

`psvm` stands for `public static void main` as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // Your code here
}
```

`psvm` is not a standard Java terminology. You can call it as a Java slang. It is the entry point in your standalone Java application i.e. when you run an executable jar, it will execute the class having `psvm`. There are so much of content about it on the internet e.g. https://dzone.com/articles/executable-java-applications

Comment: I don't think it would be "Java slang" without the IDE shortcut.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte - IMHO, Java slangs is not the same as the [IDE shortcuts](https://www.cloudflight.io/press/intellij-idea-eclipse-shortcuts-1689/) which are mostly different for different IDEs.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813153/what-is-the-eclipse-shortcut-for-public-static-void-mainstring-args I see that it's not available in Eclipse, unless you add it. But it is available by default in both NetBeans and IntelliJ, so that's two of the three major Java IDEs.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte - Good to know...being a Eclipse user, I am so used to using `main + control + space` that I think it will be difficult for me to use `psvm` ... even if this option can be configured.

Comment: As it turns out, "main" then Tab in NetBeans works just as well as "psvm" then Tab. Probably the same in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

The main() is the first entry point of Java application. Java Virtual Machine is told to run an application by specifying its class using the application launcher & it will look for the main() with exact syntax of public static void main(String[]).

Answer (score 1):

Considering your comments you want to do something like this :

```
public class Starter{
  public static void main(String args) {
    new Starter().run();
  }
  public void run() {
    //your logic
  }
}
```

once you write this, 
you have multiple options to run this I am mentioning a few

1) by building jar and then executing that jar using java -jar command

2) or by executing maven command once you have compiled your program using **mvn compile**, **mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="complete name of your main class i.e including package name."**

a few links 
[http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Maven_SE/Maven.html)
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Maven_SE/Maven.html

hope this might help

Comment: just to add a few point that might be helpful @Commander300 you can view thiese links https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Maven_SE/Maven.html      http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/

Comment: Thank you a lot, but I wanna run my application from IDE by click "Run" next to psvm

Comment: First you need to decide how you wanna run it, from maven or ide , and above code will also run from ide , there will be no issue